# recursion error happens with Skip compiling polyquinticconst.py when run py2app

Tags: python-3.x, py2app

I want to deploy my python APP to another computer, so i use

```
python setup.py py2app
```

instead of

```
python setup.py py2app -A
```

but recursion error also happens, below is the log

```
`running py2app
creating /.../build/bdist.macosx-11.0-arm64/python3.10-standalone/app
creating /.../build/bdist.macosx-11.0-arm64/python3.10-standalone/app/collect
creating /.../build/bdist.macosx-11.0-arm64/python3.10-standalone/app/temp
creating build/bdist.macosx-11.0-arm64/python3.10-standalone/app/lib-dynload
creating build/bdist.macosx-11.0-arm64/python3.10-standalone/app/Frameworks
**RecursionError while compiling code, skip scanning bytecode **
**Skip compiling '/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sympy/polys****/polyquinticconst.py' due to recursion error **`
```

Does this means error happens in polyquinticconst.py ？How can i deal with this？
In my code i import

```
from scipy import interpolate
np.set_printoptions(precision=6)
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
poly = interpolate.lagrange(xdata, ydata)
```

I am not sure whether this is the root cause

I do follow test

1. use python setup.py py2app -A, it works normal, but can used in another computer
2. change precision from 10 to 6, recursion error  can be produced again
   Can someone know how can i packet my python APP?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred because python file, not display as graphic application.This is just static image, which open not through out python launcher, which `py2app` support only. And for future, anaconda interpreter not support `py2app` compilation.

Comment: ， so any suggestion about how to fix the issue，do i need

Comment: With scipy you can not compile application.But you can create twitter application with `scipy` graphics.There tutorial: [link](https://steemit.com/utopian-io/@hadif66/tutorial-embeding-scipy-matplotlib-with-tkinter-to-work-on-images-in-a-gui-framework)